# How to Publish Asp.net core to Azure Web App when using SQLlite Locally

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I built an asp.net core 5.0 app and used [SQLlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli) locally. When I try to publish into Aruze web app using Visual Studio 2019 community I get an error.

> Executing command: dotnet ef migrations script --no-build --idempotent
> --configuration Release --output "ApplicationDbContext.sql" --context ApplicationDbContext

> System.NotSupportedException: Generating idempotent scripts for
> migration is not currently supported by SQLite. For more information,
> see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723262.

My startup.cs looks like this:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
 if (Environment.IsProduction())
 { 
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContex"));
 }
 else
 {  
  options.UseSqlite("Data Source = Application.db");                        
 }
});
```

Seems like when the publishing is running it is using the SQLlite setting instead of the setting for the azure sql database.

How can I configure Visual Studio 2019 Publishing to create the migration for the Azure SQl database?

**Update 1:**
Publish offers two settings for *Configuration*: Debug or Release

I was able to get the Publish feature to use the correct database by setting the Publish configuration to Release (which is the default) and using *If DEBUG*

```cs
  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationConnection"));

#if DEBUG    
  options.UseSqlite("Data Source = Application.db");
#endif
```

**Update 2:**
As @poke pointed out the migration are platform-specific and the migration files for SQLlite do not always work for MS SQL. When using the migration files generated with SQLlite and publishing to Azure Web app and using azure sql database, I got this error: *Column 'Id' in table 'IdentityUser' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.*

Looking at the code in the migration file the Id column is set to Text! I do not think SQL is happy with that.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20210601213159_InitialCreate')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [IdentityUser] (
        [Id] TEXT NOT NULL,
        [UserName] TEXT NULL,
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `dotnet ef` from the command line, it might not run with the Production environment by default. So I would suggest you to explicitly set the environment first:

E.g. with PowerShell:

```
$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = 'Production'
dotnet ef migrations script
```

Or cmd:

```
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
dotnet ef migrations script
```

Since `dotnet-ef` 5.0, you should also be able to pass the environment as an application parameter directly by using the `--` separator:

```
dotnet ef migration script -- --environment Production
```

Note that migrations are usually provider-dependent, so migrations created for SQLite may not work with SQL Server. I would generally recommend using SQL Server for development locally too if that’s what your production environment uses. You can use LocalDB as a lightweight target that is mostly compatible with a full SQL Server.